# Django dumpdata from a python script

Tags: django, python-2.7

Im trying to do a dump data from a script like this:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.management import call_command

settings.configure()
call_command('dumpdata','document_manager.%s' % model_name,format='json',indent=3,stdout=output)
```

This produces the error:

```
Unknown application: document_manager
```

The script is within another directory, its not an app, just a directory, I added an

```
__init__.py
```

file in this directory

Running the dumpdata from within the root of the app, it works. I guess its something todo with relative position of the script? I should I be doing this?

settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',

    'document_manager',
)
```

the dir structure looks like this: (django 1.5)

```
myappname
  /myappname
    settings.py
  /document_manager
  /cleaner
    __init__.py
    my_script.py
```

Comment: application document_manager in INSTALLED_APPS ?

Comment: yes, it is. I should have put that in the questioin

Comment: please give more details about the paths of your script and django app

Comment: I updated the question, please have a look

Comment: When running the command in terminal it works both from the root of the app and within the cleaner dir.. using python manage.py dumpdata ... and python ../manager.py ...

Comment: @Harry, how do you want to run your script? Do you want to have another management command, e.g. python manage.py my_script, or you want to call it from web interface?

Comment: I want it to run from a scheduler directly calling the .py file

Comment: I moved the script to the root dir and now it works

Answer (score 4):

I advise you to use another method:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/

To begin to create a structure:

```
document_manager/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    management/
        __init__.py
        commands/
            __init__.py
            specdumpdata.py
    tests.py
    views.py
```

In specdumpdata.py:

```
from django.core.management.commands.dumpdata import Command as DumpDataCommand


class Command(DumpDataCommand):

    def handle(self, *app_labels, **options):
        # override options, app_labels and code method

        # with or without ...
        super(Command, self).handle(*app_labels, **options)
```

Run command in virtual environment:

`python manage.py specdumpdata`

Comment: How would the scheduler (windows) in this example run this in the virtual environment?